# I am getting a “You are currently banned from flagging…” message but no clear end for this ban is given

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

Title says it all. I went to flag something as SPAM on the main *Super User* site recently and got a message (see screenshot below) that states, “You are currently banned from flagging…”

Okay, fair enough. I understand declined flags can add up and result in a flagging ban which I understand is a temporary “muzzle” on flags and I’m cool with that. But in this case clear end for this ban is given. Am I banned for flagging forever or is message a user interface error? I don’t see an end date.

[image]

And here is the normal flagging screen where it tells me I can’t flag and I should review flags, but again no clear end date is given.

[image]

Comment: It's not forever in this case, it's formorrow

Comment: You're right that you can't see it on any display on your end, but there is a note for moderators about when a suspension will end. But that's beside the point of you not knowing when yours will currently run out, or if you would be able to see it in future

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268607/i-dont-know-how-long-im-flag-banned-for-and-that-would-be-useful-to-know although this report is a lot more detailed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the next build, the ban message on your flag summary page will indicate how long you must wait before flagging again:

> [image: You may raise flags again in 7 days]

Fair warning: flag ban durations are calculated on demand. If more flags are declined after you view this message, the duration may be extended; if more flags are marked helpful, the ban may be lifted entirely. You should treat this as informational, but not conclusive.